# How to hide control buttons in ExoPlayer2

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

How to hide all controllers in ExoPlayer2 (start button, pause, and so on) that they did not exist, and the screen was always full.

I looked, there is `simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true)` method;

But it deactivate the player ...

```
public void setUseController (boolean useController) {
    this.useController = useController;
if (useController) {
      controller.setPlayer(player);
    } else {
      controller.hide();
      controller.setPlayer(null);
    }
}
```

How to hide or delete these components?

Comment: Checkout this may helps for Jetpack Compose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977304/3974530

Answer (score 92):

ExoPlayer-r2.2.0 used

```
videoView.hideController();
videoView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlaybackControlView.VisibilityListener() {
    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if(visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            videoView.hideController();
        }
    }
});
```

or

app:use_controller="false" in Layout

```
<...
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:use_controller="false"/>
```

Comment: when using app:use_controller="false" then click event not working on the exoplayer2

Comment: I just want to play video, the clicklistener is still showing the control even with use_controller set to false

Comment: Checkout this may helps for Jetpack Compose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977304/3974530

Answer (score 42):

Simply use this

```
exoPlayerView.setUseController(false);
```

Comment: how to hide the next button only from the controller?

Comment: @MuhammedHaris try asking that in a new question

Comment: Checkout this may helps for Jetpack Compose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977304/3974530

Comment: After applying `setUseController(false);`. it's onclicklistener method is not working.

Answer (score 27):

Kotlin:

```
exoPlayerView.useController = false
```

Java:

```
exoPlayerView.setUseController(false);
```

XML:

```
app:use_controller="false"
```

Documentation:
https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#setUseController-boolean-

Answer (score 11):

```
exoPlayerView.setUseController(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

PlayerView has a hideController method.
you can call it like this:

`mPlayerView.hideController();`

Answer (score 6):

A simple adaptation to Jetpack compose of this answer

```
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer(myVideo: MyVideo, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            setMediaItem(myVideo.asMediaItem())
            repeatMode = ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
            playWhenReady = true
            prepare()
            play()
        }
    }
    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(
            modifier = modifier,
            factory = {
                PlayerView(context).apply {
                    player = exoPlayer
                    useController = false
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                            .MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                            .MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    ) {
        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }
}
```

This would be `asMediaItem()` extension function

```
private fun MyVideo.asMediaItem() =
    MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(url)
        .setMediaId("some-media-id")
        .setTag("some-video-tag")
        .setMediaMetadata(
            MediaMetadata.Builder().setDisplayTitle("Video").build()
        )
        .build()
```

and MyVideo class, which models a really basic video

```
data class MyVideo(val url: String, val previewImage: String)
```

The key line to remove the controls here is `useController = false`

Comment: VideoPlayer method works for me to stop video  by onDispose() Thanks!
Mine simple method is something like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977304/3974530

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem I did this:

Code in Kotlin

```
simpleExoPlayerView.setControllerVisibilityListener { visibility ->
        val layout = activity.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_customPlayBackControlView)
        if (layout.tag != "IN_ANIMATION") {
            when (visibility) {
                View.GONE -> {
                    layout.tag = "IN_ANIMATION"
                    ex_fragmentVideoView.showController()
                    layout.animate().alpha(0F).setDuration(450L).withEndAction({ ex_fragmentVideoView.hideController(); layout.tag = "" }).start()
                }
                View.VISIBLE -> {
                    layout.animate().alpha(1F).setDuration(450L).start()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

exoPlayerView.useController = false

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to only show the controller and hide the video screen. I used PlaybackControlView.

```
     <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlaybackControlView
            android:id="@+id/player_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/quantum_yellow"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use new version `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.5'`

Usage-1: Xml file : `app:use_controller="false"`

```xml
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:show_subtitle_button="true"
        argType:fastforward_increment="15000"
        argType:resize_mode="fixed_width"
        argType:rewind_increment="15000"
        argType:show_buffering="when_playing"
        argType:show_fastforward_button="true"
        argType:show_next_button="false"
        argType:show_previous_button="false"
        argType:show_rewind_button="true"
        argType:show_subtitle_button="true"
        argType:use_artwork="true"
        app:use_controller="false"
        argType:use_sensor_rotation="true" />
```

Usage-2: You can use it in Activity like this.

```kotlin
 binding.playerView.useController = false
```

Answer (score -4):

```
controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
controller.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Use either of those to set visibilty.
Android Documentation : [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)